# Categorize without taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can we categorize things on our site without using taxonomy. I have learned Taxonomy but want to know how to categorize things without Taxonomy.
Can anyone help me Please.

Comment: It depends what type of container you want for your items. You can use any other entity in Drupal for that. Lots of modules actually do that, such as [OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) which uses Nodes to be containers for other Nodes. Other examples are Book and Forum. As you probably don't want to create a module for this you would use [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to assist you. But that said Taxonomy is an entity built exactly for the purpose so first see if there are contrib modules that can extend Taxonomy to your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add "List" field type to your custom content type. By default you could choose between lists of Text, Integer and Float. While configuring you could choose whether or not it will be checkboxes, radio buttons or select lists.
Later in Views you could filter content with use of these fields.

It's in Drupal core, no additional modules (except of Views of course)